# pass the variable to child view in zend

Tags: zend-framework

I am using zend framwork 
in my controller i have set string to display in view like

**Controller**

```
$this->view->foo = 'sample string or content';
```

**main view**

```
echo $this->foo;
```

this is working fine show me string **sample string or content**
but when i call other view inside this main view its not give any output

i am caaling something like this view inside view.

```
<?=$this->myform;?>
```

**in myform.phtml**

```
echo $this->foo;
```

this is not given any output...
Please help me what i am going worng...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [Partial Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) like this:

In view:

```
<?php echo $this->partial('myform.phtml', array('foo' => $this->foo)); ?>
```

Comment: in myform.phtml i have code something like this type <?=$this->element->getElement('firstname'); ?>  so i am try with partial then its not working....

Comment: If I understand, you have in your controller this: `$this->view->element = ...`, so in your view, you do this : `echo $this->partial('myform.phtml', array('element ' => $this->element ));` and in your myform, you do `$this->element->getElement('firstname');`, exact? if yes, try to do the same thing but just with a foo variable, like your example et do a var_dump of foo in your myform.phtml

Comment: If it's not work, try to add the ditectory of myform in the partial like this: `echo $this->partial('directory/myform.phtml', array('element ' => $this->element ));`